In WinSCP I am trying to use "-rawsettings KEX=" option but KEX is not set as expected
Windows 2022 (And other Windows version), WinSCP portable, version 6.3.4 (but it is reproducible on older versions as well)
My open command is like this:
open sftp://user1:***@localhost -rawsettings KEX="dh-group14-sha1"

Commands runs fine and I am connected to the server but with different KEX. Also log shows that KEX was not changed as expected.
Here is the log – observe line starting with KEX
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Script: Retrospectively logging previous script records:
Script: open sftp://user1:***@localhost -rawsettings KEX="dh-group14-sha1"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Session name: user1@localhost (Ad-Hoc site)
Host name: localhost (Port: 22)
User name: user1 (Password: Yes, Key file: No, Passphrase: No)
Tunnel: No
Transfer Protocol: SFTP
Ping type: Off, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 15 sec
Disable Nagle: No
Proxy: None
Send buffer: 262144
Compression: No
Bypass authentication: No
Try agent: Yes; Agent forwarding: No; KI: Yes; GSSAPI: Yes
GSSAPI: KEX: No; Forwarding: No; Libs: gssapi32,sspi,custom; Custom: 
Ciphers: aes,chacha20,aesgcm,3des,WARN,des,blowfish,arcfour; Ssh2DES: No
KEX: ntru-curve25519,ecdh,dh-gex-sha1,dh-group18-sha512,dh-group17-sha512,dh-group16-sha512,dh-group15-sha512,dh-group14-sha1,rsa,WARN,dh-group1-sha1
SSH Bugs: Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto
Simple channel: Yes
Return code variable: Autodetect; Lookup user groups: Auto
Shell: default

Note the same was true if I want to modify Cipher option
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Indeed, your setting has no effect. It only allows use of that algorithm. And as it is allowed already by default, it makes no difference.
If you want to prioritize that algorithm over all others, you need to provide complete list with that algorithm at front:
open sftp://... -rawsettings KEX=dh-group14-sha1,ntru-curve25519,ecdh,dh-gex-sha1,dh-group18-sha512,dh-group17-sha512,dh-group16-sha512,dh-group15-sha512,rsa,WARN,dh-group1-sha1

If you want to disallow all other algorithms, move WARN token before them.
